# Куда подевались ресурсы?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

Rails 5.1 с дефолтными настройками Webpack для Vue.

После выполнения этой команды компилируются обычные ресурсы в директорию *public/assets*, а также Webpack ресурсы в директорию *public/packs*:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

Далее я запускаю приложение:

```
rails s -p 3000 -e production
```

В итоге не загружается ни один из .css или .js файлов, будь то обычный из *public/assets* или от Webpack из *public/packs*.

Браузер ругается:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:3000/assets/footer/application-df03972cd6b7c8a19a13ded266384bc010eb38924f430f4fbedc4be050fe9dca.js
>
> http://localhost:3000/packs/news-1f18ee09ff91de434bbb.js

Файлы с такими именами находятся в своих директориях. Я не могу понять в чем дело...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Вебсервер приложения в боевом режиме не раздаёт статические файлы.

И это нормально. В продакшене принято эту задачу поручать обратному прокси, стоящему перед сервером.

Обычно это NginX с такой директивой [`try_files`](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), что на входящий запрос сервер сначала попытается отдать просто файл из файловой системы по указанному пути, а если такового не окажется, то передаст запрос приложению.

Но если вам прямо очень надо, это настраивается в `config/environments/production.rb`, опция `config.public_file_server.enabled`.

Comment: Блин, точно! Что со мной не так, мы же вроде уже это проходили...