# Почему недоступны assets после успешного деплоя?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dokku

После успешного деплоя, заходя на сайт, все assets приложения недоступны. Притом на сервере в директории /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff появляется множество новых каталогов, связанных с одним деплоем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом нижнем находятся исходные файлы приложения. В предпоследнем уже имеется заполненная скомпилированными assets директория public (включая файлы Webpack), но нет исходных файлов приложения. В остальных каталогах нет ничего интересного - логи да прочее, файлов приложения нет.

Это скриншот содержимого каталога public: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNoxf.png

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1

ENV APP_ROOT=/app

ENV RAILS_ENV=production
ENV RACK_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils && \
    apt-get install -y automake nodejs yarn libpq-dev imagemagick libmagick++-dev libxml2-dev && \
    apt-get clean

WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN gem install bundler --no-document && \
    bundle install --binstubs --deployment --clean --without development test && \
    yarn install

COPY . .

RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: [А мы точно не разговаривали об этом ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684034/181100)?

Comment: @D-side не. Тут дело в Dockerfile судя по всему.

Comment: Ну, я пока не вижу ни единого симптома того, почему бы нет. Докер ведь только сервер приложения держит, и по умолчанию он ассеты в продакшене не раздаёт.

Comment: @D-side в целом я использую Dokku. Вот он нормально assets готовил у меня ранее. Перешел на Dockerfile и вот сейчас столкнулся с этой проблемой.

Comment: Это всё так же не добавляет ни одного повода думать, что проблема не в том же.

Comment: @D-side я вас понял и... Похоже вы реально угадали. Пока вернулся на  `.buildpacks`, так как время поджимает. Но скоро я вернусь к этому вопросу. Пока что я так и не понял как наладить работу с Rails, Nginx и Dockerfile...

Comment: @Colibri это известная проблема, связанная с тем, что статику надо собирать вроде бы в nginx, но само приложение лежит совсем в другой стороне. Есть несколько решений, но все так себе, кроме, пожалуй, целенаправленного отделения фронтенда от бэкенда.